# Can I use one curly brace instead of two curly braces in React props?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have some exmple , but i understand.

```
 const Links = () =>
 <nav>
   <Link activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/">Home</Link>
   <Link activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/about">About</Link>
   <Link activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/contact">Contact</Link>
</nav>
```

can i just write that`<Link activeStyle={color: 'red'} to="/">Home</Link>`
i lose an pair of brace.braces have some meaning?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that makes sense. *I don't know why do that* conveys no information about the problem you have or the question you're asking. Your title should be something that will have meaning to future readers of this site who find it in a search result.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this, because the first pair of curly braces puts you in a Javascript context, the next pair of curly braces is an object literal defining your style.

```js
<Link activeStyle={{color: 'red'}} to="/">Home</Link>
```

Is the same as:

```js
var style = {
  color: 'red'
};

<Link activeStyle={style} to="/">Home</Link>
```

You CANNOT do this:

```js
<Link activeStyle=style to="/">Home</Link>
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider marking it the correct one to help others.